# Windows 7 .lnk file association

Tags: windows-7, file-association

A malware created a .lnk file association with notepad. I can't figure out how can I remove the file association and I can't run any shortcut on my computer.

Help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily restore the correct registry settings by downloading the `lnk` reg file from here

http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/19449-default-file-type-associations-restore.html

Run that and it will re-associate your shortcuts as normal.

Answer (score 1):

At the core, file extension handlers are registered in Windows Registry, under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` .

Check under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.lnk` key for the association and details. (I'm pretty sure there's a way to change this in control panel as well.) You'll have to restore this key from a machine that is not infected.

Note that this is a workaround than a solution. Try using an anti-malware app to remove the infection first, otherwise it will overwrite the registry again.

> PLEASE DO NOT EDIT THE REGISTRY IF YOU DON'T UNDERSTAND WHAT IT DOES. IT MAY CAUSE SYSTEM INSTABILITY.